# Handling Html5 Video + Mp4 source ONLY in Old Browsers

Tags: html, cross-browser, html5-video, mp4

How to error handle html5 video + only mp4 source under old browsers.
Most of the browsers have support for html5 but not mp4. How to detect this and output an error for the user?

Keep in mind these things:

- The client will use only mp4
- The video element will be used multiple videos all mp4
- Convertion mp4 to webmm/ogg is not a solution in this case

I need only a way to generate error for browsers that won't play the video. How to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [HTMLMediaElement.canPlayType()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType) and get the value if your browser  support mp4 or not.

```
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    console.log(video.canPlayType('video/mp4')); // "maybe"
```

Possible answers are:

- 'probably': The specified media type appears to be playable.
- 'maybe': Cannot tell if the media type is playable without playing it.
- '' (empty string): The specified media type definitely cannot be played.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can handle it as below.

```
    var videoSource1 = '<source src="//anc.com/video1.webm" type="video/webm"/>';
    var videoSource2 = '<source src ="//abc.com/video2.mp4" type = "video/mp4"/>';
    var videoSource = videoSource1 + videoSource2;
   $('.video-container').append(videoSource);
```

The above code will detect any one of file on the basis of browser support.